# Twitter Bootstrap style default JS alert

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to style default JS alerts using Twitter Bootstrap? For example:

```
alert("You can select maximum 8 files at once.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't style normal alert windows. Their look and feel is controlled by the OS. The best you can do is shadow the real `alert` function with one of your own. For example, you could override `alert` with a function that writes the message to console instead:

```
​alert = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);  
};

alert("Hello");
```

In your custom `alert` method you could open one of [Bootstrap's modal windows](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) with the message.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/J97Ns/) of the above code.